# Laravel / Eloquent: how to hook into the deletion process?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

When a record gets deleted from `my_items_table` I want to insert the record into `my_items_table_archive`.

I could do this on each Controller, but would **prefer to hook into the Eloquent model**.

Is there anything like this?

**Pseudocode:**

```
class MyItem extends Model {
    protected function beforeDelete($record) {
        MyItemArchive::create($record); // add record the archive
        return true; // continue deletion of $record 
    }
}
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is something similar to your pseudocode.

You can utilise [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events)

A good example of this can be seen below:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'deleted' => UserDeleted::class,
    'deleting' => UserDeleting::class
];
```

The class in question just needs to adhere to / Follow: [Listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#defining-listeners)

You can also use Eloquent Observers / the observer pattern to achieve a similar result.

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Thanks, ExohJosh. That's exactly what I've needed.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all create a new Observer using

```
php artisan make:observer MyItemObserver
```

Then

```
<?php


namespace App\Observers;


class MyItemObserver
{

    public function deleting(MyItem $myItem)
    {
     /// insert new record here
    }
}
```

Now you in your `appServiceProvider`

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        MyItem::observe(MyItemObserver::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now your obverserver will be hooked to Model Events.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events) you have two choices using the events. The first one is creating an observer like this:

```
class MyModelObserver
{

    /**
    * Listen to the Model deleting event.
    *
    * @param  User  $user
    * @return void
    */
    public function deleting(User $user)
    {
      // HERE YOUR CODE TO TRANSFER THE MODEL
    }

  }
```

Than you have to register it on your `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function boot {
  MyModel::observe(MyModelObserver::class)
}
```

Otherwise you can add these events in your model by generating the specific class:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'deleting' => MyModelDeletingEvent::class,
];
```

Anyway if you're using a version of laravel lower than 5.4 you should check the documentation for the specific implementation, since the `$dispatchesEvents` is not available as variable.